# access private vars in tests in Scala without casting

Tags: scala, casting, pattern-matching

i need your help with this Scala issue that i have.

I have a hierarchy of classes: Vehicle that has only common variables of every vehicle and then 3 subclasses: Car, Truck and MotorCycle, everyone with its own specific variables.
I am using pattern matching in an auxiliary object method to do some transformations depending of the type of vehicle:

```
object Transformation {
    def someTransformation(vehicle:Vehicle):Vehicle = {
        vehicle match {
            case Car(<<<vars>>>) => Car(<<< transformed vars>>>)
            case Truck(<<<vars>>>) => Truck(<<< transformed vars>>>)
            case MotorCycle(<<<vars>>>) => MotorCycle(<<< transformed vars>>>)
        }
    }
}
```

my problem is when i have to test it, as i am returning a Vehicle (lets say a mixin), i have to cast every time it appears in order to access to the private vars of the vehicle involved.
I want a way to leave this code as it is and in tests access private members without casting, knowing that the vehicle i received as param is the same type as the vehicle i returned.
This can be addressed by generics?, how?

THANK YOU, i hope its understandable.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't really mean `private` members of the class, just subclass-specific?

Comment: exactly Nimrod Argov

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is place a restriction on the return type of the function `someTransformation`. You want `someTransformation` to only return the type of vehicle that it is called on.

Here's how you can do this with context bounds:

```
trait Vehicle
case class Car(a: Int) extends Vehicle
case class Truck(b: Int) with Vehicle
case class MotorCycle(c: Int) with Vehicle

object Transformation {
  trait Transformer[V <: Vehicle] {
    def transform(v: V): V
  }

  implicit val carTransformer = new Transformer[Car] {
    override def transform(c: Car): Car = Car(c.a + 1)
  }

  implicit val truckTransformer = new Transformer[Truck] {
    override def transform(t: Truck): Truck = Truck(t.b + 10)
  }

  implicit val motorCycleTransformer = new Transformer[MotorCycle] {
    override def transform(m: MotorCycle): MotorCycle = MotorCycle(m.c + 100)
  }

  def someTransformation[V <: Vehicle : Transformer](v: V): V = {
    implicitly[Transformer[V]].transform(v)
  }
}

Transformation.someTransformation(Car(1)) // results in Car(2)
Transformation.someTransformation(Truck(1)) // results in Truck(11)
Transformation.someTransformation(MotorCycle(1)) // results in MotorCycle(101)
```